# Custom docker image not working with helm install

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, amazon-eks, newrelic

I am trying to install [Containerized Private Minion](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/synthetics/synthetic-monitoring/private-locations/install-containerized-private-minions-cpms/) but facing error in below

Using a Dockerfile, while making a custom image that allows containers created from them to establish a SSL handshake with endpoints, The error appears as below.

Here I have added command to create /etc/certs since it is not pre existing. Also I am not sure if /opt/java/openjdk/lib/security/cacerts exists on container

```
FROM quay.io/newrelic/synthetics-minion:latest
RUN mkdir /etc/certs
COPY Cert.pem /etc/certs
RUN keytool -noprompt -import -alias proxy -file /etc/certs/Cert.pem -keystore /opt/java/openjdk/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit
```

I used docker build minionwithcert , but the image created had no repo name & was , I manually tagged the image with a name. It looks like to me the custom image was not properly created, & either the Dockerfile is wrong or a mistake in docker run command.

Error:

```
 Failed to pull image "minionwithcert:3.0.65": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: pull access denied for minionwithcert, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
  Warning  Failed                  3m8s (x4 over 4m45s)   kubelet                  Error: ErrImagePull
  Warning  Failed                  2m43s (x6 over 4m44s)  kubelet                  Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   BackOff                 2m31s (x7 over 4m44s)  kubelet                  Back-off pulling image "minionwithcert:3.0.65"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test an image locally, use its IMAGE ID. Example:

If your image is:

```
docker image ls
REPOSITORY    TAG     IMAGE ID      CREATED        SIZE
<none>        <none>  a1510947ccde  2 minutes ago  436 MB
```

You can run it using:

```
docker run a1510947ccde
```

Once you tag it, docker tries to download it from a registry.